# C# MySql.Data.MySqlClient Create database failed

Tags: c#, mysql, prepared-statement

I wanted to create a new database using the MySql.Data.MySqlClient with prepared statements. Unfortunately it shows me an error message "You have an error with your SQL syntax". Using "test" for the iv_name import value of the method.

When executing "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test;" directly in mysql server console, it works without any problems. When adding "'" to left and right of the @dbname a database will be created called @dbname in my mysql server.

```
public void CreateDatabase(string iv_name)
    {
        MySqlCommand lo_cmd = new MySqlCommand("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS @dbname;", this._conn);
        lo_cmd.Prepare();
        lo_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbname", iv_name);
        lo_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Here you can find a screen shot from the debuggin process

[image: error while creating a new database - debugger result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use parameters in data definition SQL statements like CREATE TABLE. Use string concatenation to create statements like that.

Be very careful with user-provided table names. Avoid punctuation and avoid reserved words like ‘select‘ and ‘table'. Your best bet is to reject any user input containing punctuation other than `_`, and to prefix user input with something like `t_`. So you reject `table;droptable` and turn `mytable` into `t_mytable`.

Comment: When using string concatenation, is there a method to check or convert the iv_name value for avoiding mysql injections? Or do i have manually check it by iv_name.Contains(" ' "); for example?